# PHPUnit Form Test Failing on DateTime

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have several unit tests failing on my local machine because DateTime values differ:

```
4) Tests\AppBundle\Form\AssetStatusTypeTest::testValidForm with data set #0 (array('active'))
Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
     'status' => 'active'
    'type' => null
    'amount' => null
-    'createdAt' => 2018-09-20T20:34:47.047520+0200
+    'createdAt' => 2018-09-20T20:34:47.047870+0200
     'updatedAt' => null
     'contract' => null
     'admin' => null
```

The test:

```
public function testValidForm($data)
{
    $form = $this->factory->create(AssetStatusType::class);
    $object = Entity::fromArray(new Asset(), $data);
    $form->submit($data);
    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
    $this->assertEquals($object, $form->getData());
    $view = $form->createView();
    $children = $view->children;
    foreach (array_keys($data) as $key) {
        $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
    }
}
```

Which is more or less [copied from the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html).

Now, the `createdAt` field is set like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (empty($this->createdAt)) {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

My main point is: This test is passing on our Jenkins. It does not locally on several developer machines. My first impulse was to check ini timezone settings.

I wonder how this is even possible. If I get it right, expected is when `object` was created and actual is when the form is submitted. So both objects can never have the same `createdAt` timestamp. Unless `precision` is probably super low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two machines are running different versions of PHP.  PHP7.1 (and above) includes microseconds when it creates a DateTime object, but code running on PHP 5.x and 7.0, won't.

There are two ways to work with this:

- Don't compare exact DateTimes, but convert them to seconds with `$datetimeObj->format('U');`. You'll still get occasional test failures when one test is created at say 1.99998 and the next call to create a datetime is at 2.0001, and so the test still fails when converted to seconds.
- Use '[Clock Mocking](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-clock-mocking-and-time-sensitive-tests)'. Using some interesting PHP namespace tricks, the global `time()` function is overridden (`sleep()` too). You have to create new DateTime object to make sure they actually use the new version of the time() function, but the clock would effectively stop - and sleep()'s just turn into something more like `$time += $seconds;` - which also means that a `sleep(3600);` takes effective zero time.

The symfony/phpunit-bridge ClockMock.php can be used just as a library if you don't want to include it as a listener in your PHPunit configuration.